# Visual Basic 6 - using the control's name in its own event code snippet

Tags: winforms, vba, events, vb6

Was wondering if it is possible to use a control's name in its own event sub without specifically hard coding it's name, so it can be used on other control's events, of the same type, with the exact same syntax.

for example:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Me.Caption = "Hello"

End Sub
```

Will set the containing form's caption to "hello".if i copy the same line of code to another form, it will set its caption to "hello, and so on.

i was wondering if there's another keyword for the control Command1 itself, so i'll be able to to copy-paste the same code to another command button without hard coding the name of the control.

after years of writing code in vb6, I'm 90% sure it can not be done, but it's worth the shot.

Comment: [According to this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw640fe8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) there is none.

Comment: Maybe a control array will help you. See Help

Comment: VB translates windows messages into events. Each window has a message queue, programs examine messages, decide what to do, if they don't handle it they pass it to DefWindowProc (so title bars and frames will get drawn correctly for instance even if your program does nothing). See https://www.google.com.au/search?q=vb6+window+subclass

Comment: Create a class that handles control clicks and other settings (such as captions). Then create an object of this class for each control and link the control to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with the Microsoft Script Control -- add one to your form, and then you can do, as per your example:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    ScriptControl1.AddObject "me", ActiveControl, True

    ScriptControl1.ExecuteStatement "me.Caption = ""Hello"""

    ScriptControl1.Reset

End Sub
```

If you don't already have the Script Control -- check Project/Components for Microsoft Script Control 1.0 (which is msscript.ocx) -- you can download it here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1949

Comment: This does work, although it depends on the active control being the control you want to change.Because of that dependency you could just call `Me.ActiveControl.Caption = "Hello"`

Comment: Or even drop the entirely redundant `Me.` from that.

Comment: Oops, yeah, you're right -- the Script Control is not needed there at all.